# what happens to references pointing to properties of deleted NSManagedObject

Tags: ios

I have a `NSManagedObject A` with `retain` properties `a,b,c`

I create an `NSObject B` which hold strong/retain references to `a,b,c`

Later, `NSManagedObject A` got deleted.

Would references in **B** pointing to `a,b,c` will still be valid??

I did not want to copy/duplicate **A**.

Comment: It depends what else is holding a reference to those properties.

Comment: nothing else. Please assume only A and B

Comment: I misunderstood; so you have two objects retaining some/all of the properties.  In that case the properties are still retained, after one object is deleted, so they won't be deleted.